# Cannot get sympy to compute inverse laplace transform

Tags: python, sympy

I have a function of x and s in sympy. I would like to compute the inverse Laplace transform of this expression. Following the [docs](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/integrals/integrals.html), I proceeded with the following:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> t,s,x,v_0, L, c = symbols('t, s, x, v_0, L, c')
>>> expr
-v_0*exp(s*x/c)/(s*(-exp(L*s/c) + exp(-L*s/c))) + v_0*exp(-s*x/c)/(s*(-exp(L*s/c) + exp(-L*s/c)))
>>> expr.simplify()
v_0*(-exp(L*s/c) + exp(s*(L + 2*x)/c))*exp(-s*x/c)/(s*(exp(2*L*s/c) - 1))
>>> inverse_laplace_transform(expr,s,t)
-v_0*InverseLaplaceTransform(exp(s*x/c)/(-s*exp(L*s/c) + s*exp(-L*s/c)), s, t, _None) + v_0*InverseLaplaceTransform(1/(-s*exp(L*s/c)*exp(s*x/c) + s*exp(-L*s/c)*exp(s*x/c)), s, t, _None
```

The `inverse_laplace_transform` command is called properly but returns `InverseLaplaceTransform` objects. Do I need to unwrap these or is this too complex for `sympy` to handle?

Comment: Looks too complex. A side remark: calling `expr.simplify()` does not change `expr` at all. SymPy objects are immutable, so the only way to change `expr` is to assign to it: `expr = expr.simplify()`. (It does not help here, though). Another thing to try is to declare positive symbols as such (`positive=True`) and real as `real=True`. This doesn't help, either.